# Fan not working on Raspberry Pi 4 model B

Tags: pi-4, 64-bit

I don't know if anyone's had this problem before. I just got my hands on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model G (4 GB) as well as a case that came with a DC fan.

When I went to configure the fan to turn on at 65 degrees Celsius through GPIO pin 17 (using `sudo raspi-config`), it wouldn't turn on. Even when my Pi went well over 65 degrees, the fan would refuse to spin.

I already ruled out the fan being faulty since I plugged it into a 3.3 V pin and got it to spin.

I double checked my configuration files, everything looks good. Is there anything I could be doing wrong? I've done this before with a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B already and it worked fine. I also tried other GPIO pins, none of them seem to work.

Here's the configuration from my `config.txt` file:

```
[all]

enable_uart=1

dtoverlay=w1-gpio [all]

dtoverlay=gpio-fan,gpiopin=17,temp=60000
```

It isn't working on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B either.

Comment: What case? What fan? How is it connected?

Comment: Connected the fan straight to the gpio (which I know is not always a good idea, but I'm low on options) with two wires. I am using the iUniker case with the provided fan.